# Windows Hello convenience PIN - stored on device in plain text?

Tags: windows-hello

I have received information that, in the case of using the Windows Hello convenience PIN (not Windows Hello for Business), the PIN is stored on the device in plaintext. However, I haven't found any sources or articles on this topic to confirm whether it is indeed true or not. Do you have any information about this?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you already tried googling?

Comment: "Somebody told me something. Is it true?" is a tough question in general. It will be important to know what *exactly* you were told. Because the short answer is: no

Comment: @schroeder I had security audit in company, and they recommend me to disable this feature, because we don't have Hello for Business and solution we are currently using is not secure. So "someone" was auditor.

Comment: Then this is simple: ask them for the reference that explains that. If they are recommending something and state a risk, then they need to back that up. You shouldn't have to chase up in a Q&A site the basics of what you were told by someone you hired.

Comment: Alternatively, you can check them out: https://superuser.com/questions/1414966/where-is-the-windows-10-pin-stored

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not. That would be an absurd error, and if it were true, somebody would have used it to make bank on Microsoft's bug bounty, there would be tools to easily retrieve it from disk (instead of the tools that actually exist, which can only attempt to brute-force the hash), etc.

I'm trying to find the research paper that really digs into this, but there are some sources from people who have put in the work to reverse engineer Windows Hello PINs with the goal of cracking them. https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-10461.html indicates that, *on machines without an enabled TPM*, Windows Hello PINs are hashed with PBKDF2-SHA256, using a unique salt per PIN and an iteration count that, as of Nov 2021, was 10,000.

---

With all that said: be aware that the security of Windows Hello in general, and PINs in particular, does have some weaknesses. These are, to be clear, weaknesses *relative to what might be expected of a modern authentication system*, not relative to conventional Windows passwords (which have much worse weaknesses; notably they use a very old, single-round, common-salted password hash; when Windows Hello is used instead, the password is stored encrypted using a key indirectly protected by the PIN).

In particular, note that *on machines without an enabled TPM*, Windows Hello PINs are effectively "just" passwords, and need to be protected accordingly. See https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2022/08/breaking-windows-passwords-lm-ntlm-dcc-and-windows-hello-pin-compared/ for an estimated time requirement. Brute-forcing a 4-digit or even 6-digit numeric PIN takes very little time (a minute or less on modern CPUs, never mind GPUs), despite the use of PBKDF2. If you don't have a TPM and are using Windows Hello, **you really need to enable the "include letters and symbols" option and use a proper password (or passphrase)**, ideally a reasonably long one (certainly at least eight characters, ideally 10 or more). On machines with TPMs, though, that kind of brute-force attack isn't viable; the TPM verifies the PIN internally (so the attacker can't extract the hash for offline cracking), and won't allow a large number of failed attempts in sequence.

Comment: Is there a difference between a PIN and "convenience PIN"?

Comment: @schroeder In the context of Windows Hello (the new FIDO2/Passkey-enabled authentication system that can also be used for local login), no. I'm not sure if any other Windows features use the term "PIN" anywhere but if they do, it's a different feature. However, the term itself is a misnomer, since the "PINs" need not be numeric.

Comment: I was seeing the terms "Hello PIN" and "Hello convenience PIN" being used separately in the same contexts, but could not confirm that they were different or not. The "Hello for Business PIN" is also discussed separately, and has a great deal around how it is secured. Which makes me suspicious that there might be different handling of a non-Business PIN, but I could not confirm.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't looked into Windows Hello for Business and am not sure what's different about that. If you find anything (about either "Convenience" or "for Business" PINs), please link it here! In my experience and according to all the research I've seen on it, though, there's only the one Windows Hello "PIN", at least for consumer accounts.